# Sufficient condition for a sequence of indepent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $0 \leq p_n \leq 1$ and put $\alpha_n = \min(p_n, 1-p_n)$. Show that, if $\sum_n \alpha_n$ converges, then on some discrete probability space there exist independent events $A_n$ satisfying $P(A_n) = p_n$.

Hint Enough

Comment: Perhaps I miss the point, but can you show an example when $p_1,p_2,...$ are given and you cannot create a suitable sequence of events?

Comment: @zoli: Hint: converse of this statement is easy to prove.